# PHP populate two demensions array from database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I trying to add data into two dimension array from database.
But always has last record. The array re-declared in each new record. This is a stupid question but how to declare array onside wile loop?  Thank you

```
   while ( $rq  = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $cars1=array
    (
      array($rq['Car'],"Ordered"=>$rq['Order'],"Sold"=>$rq['Sold'])
     );
    };
```

Comment: Do `$cars1[] = ....`

Comment: Also, on your inner array, you seem to be mixing numerically-indexed with associative.  That's likely not going to give you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `$cars1` to an empty array before the loop, otherwise if no rows are returned by the query it will be undefined if you refer to it later.

```
$cars1 = [];
```

Then append the fetched rows to it inside the loop.

```
while ($rq  = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $cars1[] = [$rq['Car'], "Ordered" => $rq['Order'], "Sold" => $rq['Sold']];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really simple.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your SQL to return the fields in the right elements already, something like

```
select Car, Order as Ordered, Sold
   ...
```

You can then assign the array directly (using `[]`) to add it to a list...

```
   $cars1 = array();
   while ( $cars1[]  = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC));
```

In MySQL there is a `fetch_all` not sure if there is one in SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

You should use append while creating $cars1 array so the final code inside the loop should look like:

```
$cars1[]=array (
   array($rq['Car'],"Ordered"=>$rq['Order'],"Sold"=>$rq['Sold']),
);
```